# How to solve Illegal inheritance from final class in Scala

Tags: scala

I have this code in Scala
when I define the `a` value, Also I call some methods in the object like `setStr` and it is very useful and amazing. But when I define my `AClass` as final, compiler will throws an exception as Illegal inheritance from final class. In some cases I should use final classes and this type of method calling after the class initiation is very useful to me, and my question is how to solve this problem

```
test("Test function call") {
    val a: AClass = new AClass {
        setStr("Pooya")
        func1(this)
    }
}

class AClass { // when I declare the class final, the compiler will raise an error
    private var str:String=""
    def setStr(str:String)={
        this.str=str
    }
    def aMethod() = print(str)
}

def func1(a: AClass) {
    a.aMethod()
}
```

Comment: This is as it should be: final classes are not meant to be inherited from. From the [Java language spec](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.1.1.2)

Comment: @S.R.I I know brother, but I did not know that this style of code extends the class

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you do `new AClass { ... }` you are creating an *anonymous class* that extends this class. When a class is `final` it cannot be extended.

One way to do what you want is like that:

```
val a: AClass = new AClass 
import a._
setStr("Pooya")
func1(this)
```

Following @Vladimir's suggestion, a slightly cleaner way:

```
val a: AClass = { val a = new AClass 
  import a._
  setStr("Pooya")
  func1(this) 
  a 
}
```

Now you can repeat that as many times as you want without making `setStr` ambiguous. For the `func1`, with its current definition, should't matter if it's in the `{}` block or not.

Comment: I would have added curly braces around the whole piece of code (starting with `new`) so the imported names won't leak to the outer scope.

Comment: If you're using Scalaz you could have something like `val a: AClass = new AClass <| { a => a.setStr("Pooya"); func1(a) }`.

Answer (score 1):

To get `final` semantics, pass in your initial state to the constructor.

The other mode is to use early definitions. Note that BClass#strs is final.

Final means that when your initializer is done, the value mustn't change.

And lose the mutable state.

But if you love or need mutability, a factory on the companion object can work whatever sanity you require when you build the object.

```
package inheritthewind

object Test extends App {
  val a = new AClass(new AInit { val str = "Pooya" })
  a.aMethod()
  val b = new {
    val str: String = "Pooya"
  } with BClass
  b.aMethod()
  val b2 = new BClass {
    val str: String = "Pooya"
  }
  b2.aMethod()  // uh no, result is "nulls"
  val c = CClass(new CPrototype { val str = "Pooya" })
  c.aMethod()
  // not allowed
  //val nope = new CClass
}

trait AInit {
  def str: String
}

final class AClass(init: AInit) {
  private final val str: String = init.str
  def aMethod() = Console println str
}

abstract class BClass {
  val str: String
  final val strs = str + "s"
  def aMethod() = Console println strs
}

trait CPrototype extends AInit

final class CClass private() {
  private var str: String = _
  def aMethod() = Console println str
}
object CClass {
  def apply(p: CPrototype): CClass = {
    val res = new CClass
    res.str = p.str
    res
  }
}
```

And

```
scala> :javap -pv inheritthewind.BClass
[snip]
  private final java.lang.String strs;
    flags: ACC_PRIVATE, ACC_FINAL

  public abstract java.lang.String str();
    flags: ACC_PUBLIC, ACC_ABSTRACT

  public final java.lang.String strs();
    flags: ACC_PUBLIC, ACC_FINAL
```